# How to unit test methods which internally use a lot of spring service beans?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

If you have methods which look like the following:

```
method(int input) {
    // do some stuff...

    int a = springServiceBean1(input);

    if (a == null) {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    // ...do some more stuff

    int b = springServiceBean2(a);

    // ...do even more stuff

    return springServiceBean3(b);
}
```

How do I write unit tests for code like that?

Right now I end up with a lot of `given(mockedBean.call()).willReturn()` statements. So the whole test is useless because if I write assertions for the output of the method, the only thing having an impact on this is the last `springService3()` (besides possible thrown exceptions).

So my guess is, one has to refactor the method first?

Comment: you are correct, short methods with single responsibility is the best practice

Comment: Well, your idea that consists in refactoring your method is the good one. Try and keep in mind that a method should do one and only one thing, so you should refactor based on that precept. Then, you should have a method that will be easier to test.. But you also may end up doing the same kind of `given(mockedBean.call()).willReturn()`, but that may be needed anyway, so you can test the whole process

Comment: You could use mockito to verify the order and/or interactions with the other services (along with asserting the method output).

Comment: The large method could be refactored to make it easier to maintain, but the resulting smaller methods should be private, and not **directly** tested.

Comment: Even if one splits this method to a few small private methods. You would still need a unit test for the method which uses all the small methods right?. Except it has not a single line of logic in it... (which is pretty hard to build in practice)